# Splicing MultiIndex (.loc not working)

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I am having trouble with slicing a MultiIndex. I have tried several tecniques by now but escept for one I don't get them to work. 
My DataFrame is composed of several rows like this:

```html
means


Out[25]: 
                              Total         DL         DM
Mouse Genotype Intensity                                 
455   cre      s          15.114886  13.626841  16.602930
               w          41.419970  33.916706  48.923234

554   wt       s          19.348266  13.747603  24.948928
               w          41.563015  37.336228  45.789802
```

What I am trying to do is to splice my df by Genotype.
The most simple way was of course slicing by index e.g.

```
    means[0:2]
```

but as I have more than one dataframe with more data I am looking for a more elegant way.

```
    means.loc[('cre')]
```

which has already worked for a identical dataframe (less rows though) doesn't work for this one as it keeps giving me the Keyerror: 'cre'

When I tried using indexers and other approaches I stumbled upon I kept getting the error that 'cre' is not in the index. But the same happened when I tried to go by names instead of levels. I can't figure out why this happens.

It would be great if someone could help me with this! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry are you after `means.loc[slice(none), slice('cre')]`?

Comment: I did already try this one as well. Gives me the same KeyError. I don't understand why

Comment: Are you sure that it exists? Look at `df.index.get_level_values(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1: `pd.IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'cre', :], :]

                              Total         DL         DM
Mouse Genotype Intensity                                 
455   cre      s          15.114886  13.626841  16.602930
               w          41.419970  33.916706  48.923234
```

#### Solution 2: `swaplevel` and `loc`

To use `loc['cre']`, `'cre'` needs to be in the first level of the multiindex.  Swapping levels fixes this.

```
df.swaplevel(0, 1).loc['cre']

                     Total         DL         DM
Mouse Intensity                                 
455   s          15.114886  13.626841  16.602930
      w          41.419970  33.916706  48.923234
```

#### Solution 3: `xs`

```
print df.xs('cre', level=1)

                     Total         DL         DM
Mouse Intensity                                 
455   s          15.114886  13.626841  16.602930
      w          41.419970  33.916706  48.923234
```

or

```
print df.xs('cre', level=1, drop_level=False)

                              Total         DL         DM
Mouse Genotype Intensity                                 
455   cre      s          15.114886  13.626841  16.602930
               w          41.419970  33.916706  48.923234
```

---

#### Timing

[image]

`xs` seems to be most performant.